# Running test cases from jar maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4

I have a .jar file, where I have packaged my maven managed java project which has few Junit test cases as well. Now I want to run test cases from my .jar file. For example, from the source code `mvn test` will run the test cases, but it is not working for .jar file.

How do I run Junit test cases from my .jar file?

Comment: What's wrong with the surefire plugin?

Comment: similar question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496846/run-junit-tests-contained-in-dependency-jar-using-maven-surefire/17061755#17061755

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the maven-jar-plugin, and include the test classes in the jar

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html

have  a look also here
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html