# Is there any way to run junits with maven generated jar?

Tags: java, maven, junit

Like

1. mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="packageName.class"
2. mvn -Dtest="className#method"

Does the above commands works or there any alternative commands on the maven generated target/jarFile ?

Couldnt find searching for such commands to run junits on the maven generated jar without applying maven plugins on the pom

Comment: The jar file do not contain junit testcases

Comment: What do you mean by `without applying maven plugins on the pom`? Do you want to run JUnit tests from within the generated jar file?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496846/run-junit-tests-contained-in-dependency-jar-using-maven-surefire ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include test classes into Maven jar and execute them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047637/how-can-i-include-test-classes-into-maven-jar-and-execute-them)

Answer (score 0):

The **generated jar doesn't contain** classes related to **unit tests**.

Maven can execute tests on the source test files, not on generated jars.

No system (not only maven) can execute unit tests because the generated jar doesn't contain the tests.