# Sharing common Springboot integration tests with jar?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Can I have a jar containing Springboot integration tests & use this jar in other modules to execute the common integration tests?

Comment: you could do this. I wouldn't recommend doing it this way though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496846/run-junit-tests-contained-in-dependency-jar-using-maven-surefire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/1116811/reverse-for-home-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found-0-patterns-ask-question.html):

> Maven projects already define a standard for a project's tests. And in
>   my opinion it doesn't make sense to make a project dependent on its
>   tests--if anything, tests would be dependent on the module under test,
>   since tests use the module, but not vice-versa.

Though if you wish to do this anyway, to answer your question: **yes it is possible.** As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061755):

> There is a new way of running a test in Maven from another jar. from
>   maven-surefire-plugin version 2.15 you can tell Maven to scan your
>   test jars for tests and run them. You don't need to extract the tests
>   jar. Just add a dependency to your test jar like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <dependenciesToScan>
            <dependency>test.jar.group:test.jar.artifact.id</dependency>
        </dependenciesToScan>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```