# Central SpringBootTest that is run in every maven-module's ApplicationContext separately

Tags: spring-boot, maven, integration-testing, applicationcontext, multi-module

We have a modularized monolith with a maven multi-module project structure using spring-boot and doing integration-testing via `@SpringBootTest` which boots a module-specific Spring ApplicationContext under which the integration-tests are performed, using full DI, JPA-Connections etc.

In all those modules we use a concept of "AdminControllers" and in **the** central "core" module - which is depended-on and `@ComponentScan` by **all** other modules - we have a central
`AdminControllerIntegrationTest` that asserts certain properties on all AdminController-Beans like the presence of Security-Related Annotations.

This "core" `@SpringBootTest` AdminControllerIntegrationTest is run once in an Application-Context specific to the `core` module, where it sees all core's beans - which is fine. However, in all other modules this IntegrationTest is *never* executed and cannot check any of their beans.

Is there any possibility to have this central `@SpringBootTest` be run automatically in **all** modules separately within their own specific ApplicationContexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something looks wrong in this setup, let me explain:

So you say, that you have a "core" module with its own `@SpringBootTest` test, which means that its a spring boot application.

On the other hand, you say, that you have modules A and B that are spring boot applications by themselves. But if so they can't depend on another spring boot application (core), I mean spring boot application module can't depend on another spring boot application module, it doesn't make sense and doesn't work in maven.

Another concert that comes to my mind: In any spring boot application we usually use "plug-in" like stuff: metering system, logging system, actuator and so forth. Usually for that purpose there are starters, we define those in maven and Spring boot application loads them automatically. However we treat them as "third-parties" in our application and never bother to run "their" tests while compiling our application. What you've described contradicts this approach.

So In my understanding (and again, I might be getting it all wrong), you should:

1. Create a starter (autoconfiguration module) out of your "core" module. It won't be a spring boot application by itself and won't have any @SpringBootTest on it. Only simple unit / integration tests (maybe driven by spring but not Spring boot in a sense of what @SpringBootTest does). You also won't have `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the pom of that module and also won't have a `main` method in any class (no `@SpringBootApplication` at all).
2. In modules A and B - plug in this autoconfiguration module, it will load automatically and will provide the required functionality. The tests of module A should test the code / flows of module A and don't need to test the functionality of the "core" module, its for "core"'s tests to check the functionality of the "core" module.
3. In modules A and B, when you have `@SpringBootTest` the core module will be loaded and some of your code might break because it doesn't "match the expectations" of the core module (like you haven't placed the right annotation or something) - in this case the test will fail and you'll have to fix the code of the module A for example.

**Update 1**
After reading the comments:

I think its possible and the solution should include the following steps:

1. Out of the module ***core*** that contains test `AdminControllerIntegrationTest` create an additional test jar artifact. [this link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) contains technical instructions of what should be placed at the `pom.xml` of module ***core***.
2. Your spring boot application modules should depend on this test artifact the scope test, something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

3. From now it becomes tricky because it really depends on what exactly happens in the test and how spring plugs everything in. In the "easiest" situation, for this step you will have to make sure that your surefire/failsafe plugin is of 2.15+ version: This version adds support for `dependenciesToScan` option which will contain the module core so that during the build of your spring boot application the plugin will also run the `AdminControllerIntegrationTest`. At least it will be in the tests classpath... From there you might need to do some customizations at the level of spring, without seeing the code its hard to tell what happens. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496846/run-junit-tests-contained-in-dependency-jar-using-maven-surefire) for more information

Comment: thanks for your thourough answer, regarding _they can't depend on another spring boot application (core), I mean spring boot application module can't depend on another spring boot application module_

core itself is not an actual `@SpringBootApplication`, however its own IntegrationTests do indeed define an `@SpringBootTest(classes = CoreIntegrationTestApp.class)` just for the sake of booting an integration-test application-context

Comment: _we treat them as "third-parties" in our application and never bother to run "their" tests while compiling our application._
we do exactly the same and only let the maven-modules run their "own tests". in this special case i am looking for diverting from that though

Comment: _and won't have any SpringBootTest on it. Only simple unit / integration tests (maybe driven by spring but not Spring boot in a sense of what @SpringBootTest does)._
why is that important?

Comment: @hotzen: I've updated the answer. I haven't tried it by myself though, so please update whether this worked for you or you've encountered other difficulties with that. Thanks

Comment: sorry for replying that late, didnt read the notification - thanks a lot for that update, will try out `dependenciesToScan` and the links - thanks!!