# Make maven fail safe pluing to run test from included jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a test code deployed to antifactory
Based on this [Guide to using attached tests](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html)
I want to invoke that test from plugin

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
```

The test code is included as part of dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
  <type>test-jar</test>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

maven failsafe plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <configuration>
      <dependenciesToScan> 
        <dependency>org.myproject:tests</dependency>
      </dependenciesToScan>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
           <goal>integration-test</goal>
           <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am trying to invoke mvn command as

```
mvn clean verify -Dit.test=com.myproject.TestRunner
```

I am getting the error as

```
integration-test: (default) on project testproject: No test where executed!
```

Now how do I make the maven-failsafe-plugin to call the class inside the  dependency jar

--- EDIT ---

as a workaround I unzip the jar from `.m2` folder to the local folder path `target/test-classess` then it picks up the compiled code `.class` files and testing is working

Comment: Why would you like to call the tests within an packaged jar? Why not doing the test from the project which has packaged them?

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496846/run-junit-tests-contained-in-dependency-jar-using-maven-surefire/17061755#17061755 it is for surefire, but maybe for failsafe similar feature exists.

Comment: @jwpol dependenciesToScan is not working I tried id

Comment: @khmarbaise that is the requirement, dependenciesToScan was provided by the failsafe plugin but it does not have the capacity use it, may be it is not programmed that way

Comment: `failsafe plugin but it does not have the capacity use it, may be it is not programmed that way`??? Please show your full pom file and the calling...which Maven version and surefire/failsafe plugin versions you are using?

Comment: 2.22.2 added in the question maven 3.8.1